# understanding the basic variable declaration in c language

Tags: c

Generally when we declare an variable with a data type, i.e.,

```
int temp;
```

temp will be alloted 4 bytes in stack. Whenever we use temp, it means that we are pointing to the memory created for temp. 
Can we consider the temp as a pointer? Because when we use temp, it means that we are indirectly accessing the 4 bytes in the memory..?

Comment: BTW `temp` is not on the stack if it's a global variable (declared outside of functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> temp will be alloted 4 bytes in stack.

Where temp will be allocated depends where you declared it, but also on the compiler. It will be allocated in .data or .bss segments in case you declared it at file scope or as static. It will be allocated on the stack or in a CPU register in case you declared it locally. It may also be optimized away entirely if the compiler wants to do that.

> Whenever we use temp, it means that we are pointing to the memory created for temp

Kind of, but only indirectly. The compiler generating the machine code of your program knows where the variable is allocated and uses that address in the machine code.

> Can we consider the temp as a pointer?

No, it is a variable, a chunk of data which is allocated for the purpose of storing data.

A pointer on the other hand, is a chunk of data which is allocated for the purpose of storing an address.

Comment: oh ok. So when it is converted to assembly language, it fetches data from the memory created for temp. Am I right?

Comment: @SREEBALATHATAVARTHI Yes... since all variables have to be stored somewhere. They cannot be allocated in thin air.

Answer (score 3):

No, in the  case of `int temp;`, if we are saying `temp`, we are referring to the value held by the variable anmed `temp`.

if we are saying `&temp`, then we are pointing to the address of the variable `temp`.

You can read some basics about [data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) in `c`.

<sup>BTW `&` is "address of" operator. Just thought of mentioning</sup>

Comment: is 'temp' variable also present in the stack along with its respective 4 bytes? ie., in stack we have  Temp present in some address and below that address 4 bytes that is alloted to it..?

Comment: `temp` is the variable name having 4 bytes of memory, present in stack [considering local variable]. there is no `along with` part here... :-)

Comment: the address of `temp` is returned by `&temp`. Please ASAP refer a good C book and get the conecpts clear.

Comment: @SREEBALATHATAVARTHI because [on linux], `int` is defined to have 4 bytes.